question regarding a certain back propagation algorithm
I have a code snippet to calculate the gradient values used in back propagation. However, I'm unsure as to how to run the code as well as what the code is actually doing. My project requires me to essentially use the same code without any modifications. The code snippet:
    temp = -(training_y - y_hat) * grad_sigmoid(O) * grad_sigmoid(H)
    temp = temp @ np.diag(weights2[:-1].reshape(-1))
    gradient2 = training_x.T @ temp
    gradient2 /= len(training_y)

The code is expected to produce the gradient values, yet while substituting the weights, I'm being confused to put which weight in the code to get which gradient.

As you provide code snippet here you are trying to calculate gradient value for backpropogation in neural network.
(In simple we backpropogation is minimize the loss by adjusting weight form output layer to input layer).
your first line of code.
temp = -(training_y - y_hat) * grad_sigmoid(O) * grad_sigmoid(H)

here you are calculating prediction error and multiply by gradien of the sigmoid activation at output and hidden layer.
your second line of code.
temp = temp @ np.diag(weights2[:-1].reshape(-1))

Here apply this error term to the weights connecting the hidden layer to the output layer through element wise multiplication with diagonal matrix constructed from these weights.
your third line of code.
gradient2 = training_x.T @ temp
gradient2 /= len(training_y)

Here calculate the gradient for the weights connecting the hidden layer to the output layer by taking the dot product of the transposed input data and the result of the previous step.
I'm trying to tackle you confussion, ensure that you have clear understanding of neural network architecture, specifically the connection between layers and the weight matrices associated with these connection. The weights should align with the appropriate gradients based on the layer connection in your network.
